# PropertyGrid Hint with hyperlink?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Is it possible to add a clickable hyperlink into property grid hint?

I have the following on my class (that is assigned to the property grid as `SelectedObject`):

```
[Browsable(true), 
ReadOnly(false), 
Category("7. InnoDB"), 
DefaultValue(1), 
Description("Defines what happens after InnoDB transaction commit, for more details view https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit")]
public int innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit { get; set; } = 1;
```

When viewed in the property grid, the link is not clickable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the MSDN reference, the `PropertyGrid` uses two `Label`s, one for the title and one for the description:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/DocComment.cs,a0b78590be82b950

`Label` doesn't support hyperlinks. What you could do is put a `RichTextBox` over the description label, and have it display the text instead. E.g.

```
    PropertyGrid pg = new PropertyGrid() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    Control c = pg.Controls[0]; // internal DocComment control
    Label l1 = (Label) c.Controls[1];
    RichTextBox tb = new RichTextBox { Multiline = true, WordWrap = true, ReadOnly = true, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None };
    c.Controls.Add(tb);
    c.Controls.SetChildIndex(tb, 0);
    l1.TextChanged += delegate {
        tb.Text = l1.Text;
    };
    l1.SizeChanged += delegate {
        tb.Size = l1.Size;
    };
    l1.LocationChanged += delegate {
        tb.Location = l1.Location;
    };
```

Comment: Really nice idea :) I will give this a go later. Thanks +1